# The word means Focusing only on what is visible (Concentrating only on the appearance without understanding accurately)

Tags: single-word-requests, word-usage

Focusing only on what is visible
(Concentrating only on the appearance without understanding accurately)

I wanna describe as a word but I really don't know what it is.. What I want to write is 'A person who only focuses on what is seen' as a specific word.

Comment: Can you provide more context as to where this word will be used?

Comment: Single word requests should be accompanied by a sample sentence. I am voting to close as there will only be opinions.

Answer (score 3):

Such a person can be called **superficial.** [The Free Dictionary defines it as:](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/superficial)

> concerned with or comprehending only what is on the surface or obvious

Answer (score 0):

Some possibilities, definitions from [Merriam-Webster](https://unabridged.merriam-webster.com/):

[**imperceptive:**](https://unabridged.merriam-webster.com/unabridged/imperceptive) not perceptive; lacking perception

[**obtuse:**](https://unabridged.merriam-webster.com/unabridged/obtuse) lacking acuity of sensibility or perceptions; having or showing neither delicate feelings nor alert awareness

[**oblivious:**](https://unabridged.merriam-webster.com/unabridged/oblivious) lacking active conscious knowledge or awareness; unnoticing, unaware

[**shallow:**](https://unabridged.merriam-webster.com/unabridged/shallow) 3b: lacking in depth of knowledge, thought, or feeling

[**naïve**](https://unabridged.merriam-webster.com/unabridged/naive) 1: marked by simplicity, ingenuousness, or artlessness:
a: showing candor, freshness, and spontaneity unchecked by convention, social diffidence, or guile. 
b: showing lack of worldly experience: innocent, simple. 
c: unsuspecting, credulous, and unwary about duplicity or distortion

2: marked by lack of instruction, experience, perception, or learning:
a: exhibiting lack of analysis, subtlety, or depth by ready acceptance without consideration